# Ubuntu rename command regex not working

Tags: 14.04, rename, regex, batch-rename

I'm trying to use the `rename` command to rename a bunch of images in a folder.

I have this list of images,

```
image.php?x=10
image.php?x=25
image.php?x=50
image.php?x=75
```

I'm trying to rename them to `10.png`, `25.png` etc. using this regex:

`$ rename "s/image\.php\?x\=(.*)/$1\.png/g" *`

This regex works fine in for example Sublime Text, all the matches are replaced correctly...

But when I run the rename command like this, with `$0` it says `bash.png already exists` and with `$1` it says `.png` already exists, so nothing was saved!

wat do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, your shell is expanding `$1` (likely to an empty string) before passing it to the `rename` command. Try single quotes instead of double quotes around the regex:

```
rename -- 's/image\.php\?x\=(.*)/$1.png/g' *
```

(also, it should not be necessary to escape the dot in the replacement expression i.e. you can use `$1.png` in place of `$1\.png`)